# Crystal Reports text rotation

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, crystal-reports-7

Is it possible to rotate text to 90 degree in 7.0.0.0 version? There is no such option in Common tab. Using another version is not possible for some reasons.

It is necessary to rotate crosstab headings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.. You can use StrReverse({field}) for 180.